# Retaining one sub directory and deleting everything else

Tags: linux, bash, directory

Directory structure:

```bash
/parent/
/parent/child1/
/parent/child2/
.
.
.
/parent/child1/sub1/sub2/sub3/
/parent/child1/subA/subB/
/parent/child1/subX/subY/
.
.
.
/parent/child1/subX/subY/subZ/
/parent/child1/subA/subB/
```

I want to keep:

```bash
parent/child1/sub1/sub2/sub3/
```

and delete everything else in the parent folder

I have tried

```bash
find ./parent -mindepth 1  -type d -not -path "*/sub3*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But it still ends up deleting the **/parent/child2/sub1/sub2/** directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `find`'s built in `-delete`:

```
find ./parent -not -path "*/sub3*" -delete
```

Example:

```
% mkdir -p /tmp/foo/{1..5}/sub{1..35}
% touch /tmp/foo/{1..5}/{bar,sub{1..35}/more.bar}
% find /tmp/foo -not -path '*/sub3*' -delete
% find /tmp/foo | head
/tmp/foo
/tmp/foo/1
/tmp/foo/1/sub32
/tmp/foo/1/sub32/more.bar
/tmp/foo/1/sub35
/tmp/foo/1/sub35/more.bar
/tmp/foo/1/sub34
/tmp/foo/1/sub34/more.bar
/tmp/foo/1/sub33
/tmp/foo/1/sub33/more.bar
```

In your solution you use "`rm -rf {}`" which, at some point, will call:

```
rm -rf ./parent/childN
```

Comment: This worked! But as you have shown, output of: find /tmp/foo -not -path '*/sub3*'
does include parent of /sub3. How is that not deleted? I checked the man page but did not find how the parent directories are still kept. Could you please explain or provide a reference where I can read more?

Comment: cool - glad it worked.  "-delete" won't delete a directory if there is something in it, similar to `rmdir`.  i'm not sure where this would be documented.  also note that "-delete" isn't posix compliant so if that matters then you'd need to go back to using "... -depth -exec rm ..." to remove files and a second pass to remove empty directories.